# Find phone numbers regex in text file using batch

Tags: regex, batch-file

This is my first batch file attempt.
I need to extract all the phone numbers from a text file and store them all in a separate file. Any string that has 10 digits is a phone number.

```
@echo off setlocal enableDelayedExpansion (   for /f %%A in (
    'findstr "^\d{10}" print.txt'   ) do (

    echo ?????   ) )>newFile.txt
```

This is as far as i could get.

The print.txt (source file) looks something like this

```
 dsfgsf 445h ghsr 454 0775344623 0766555444 789 963 09 hgs dsfgsf 445h
 0754655321 ghsr 454 0771344623 0766222444 789 963 09 hgs
```

I would like my destination file to look something like this

```
0775344623
0766555444
0754655321
0771344623
```

or comma/space separated - it doesn't matter.

Comment: Read the help of `findstr /?` to find out what search strings it supports; there are no range/count operators `{`/`}` and there is no `\d`; what you'll need to use is probably `"^[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]"`...

Comment: And be aware that `findstr` command returns _lines_, so if your text file have additional data in each line, a further processing of the found lines is needed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your RegEx you could leverage `PowerShell` from your batch file:

```bat
@PowerShell "GC 'print.txt'|%%{[Regex]::Matches($_,'\d{10}')}|%%{$_.Value}">"newfile.txt"
```

Comment: I create a bat file `dir /b /s > filelist.txt
@PowerShell "GC 'filelist.txt'|%%{[Regex]::Matches($_,'\d{10}')}|%%{$_.Value}">"newfile.txt"`